# android icon of sub menu items not appear

Tags: android, android-menu

I have this menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sortFoods"
        android:icon="@drawable/sort_neutral"
        android:title="Sort">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/sortAlphabaticallyAsc"
                android:icon="@drawable/sort_up"
                android:title="Sort Alphabatically ASC"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/sortAlphabaticallyDes"
                android:icon="@drawable/sort_down"
                android:title="Sort Alphabatically DES"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/sortPriceAsc"
                android:title="Sort By Price ASC"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/sortPriceDes"
                android:title="Sort By Price DES"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

the icon of the item `sortFoods` is appear but the icons of the items in side it doesn't appear, why please ? what is the solution ? thank

Comment: When you click on sortFood then neseted item will be appear as in the form of dialog.

Comment: yes exactly, just the title is appeared but the icons don't

Answer (score 0):

check [Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

`Icon Menu`
This is the collection of items initially visible at the bottom of the screen at the press of the MENU key. It supports a maximum of six menu items.These are the only menu items that support icons and the only menu items that do not support checkboxes or radio buttons.